# мне нужно использовать do-while для вывода на экран положительных и отрицательных чисел

Tags: java

Я в программе использовал цикл for,а в задании нужно использовать циклы do,while,но не знаю как сделать:

```
int[] a = {8, 2, 7, -2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9, -3, -6, -8, -1, -4, -5, -7, -9};
System.out.println("Числа:\n");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
int countNegative = 0;
int countPositive = 0;
for (int value : a) {
   if (value < 0) {
       countNegative++;
   } else if(value > 0) {
       countPositive++;
   } else {
       break;
   }
}
System.out.println("\nНегативные числа:" + countNegative);
System.out.println("\nПоложительные числа:" + countPositive);
```

Comment: А в чем проблема у вас?

Comment: я в программе использовал цикл for,а в задании нужно использовать циклы do,while,но не знаю как сделать

Comment: Почему бы вам не написать это в самом вопросе?

Answer (score 0):

Вы уже задавали этот вопрос раньше и в задании было окончание при числе равным 0 (а это важно). Как-то так:

```
    int[] a = {8, 2, 7, -2, 5, 6, 3, 1, 9, -3, -6, -8, -1, 2, -5, -7, -9};
    System.out.println("Числа:\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    int countNegative = 0;
    int countPositive = 0;
    if( a.length > 0) { // проверка на нулевой массив
        int i = 0;
        do {
            int value = a[i];
            if (value < 0) {
                countNegative++;
            } else if (value > 0) {
                countPositive++;
            }
            i++;
        } while (a[i - 1] != 0 && i < a.length);
    }
    System.out.println("\nНегативные числа:" + countNegative);
    System.out.println("\nПоложительные числа:" + countPositive);

}
```

Comment: спасибо,помогли.Наверное не заметил этот ответ раньше